# How to inhibit installing from source?

Tags: homebrew

I am quite often in areas where the WIFI connection is unreliable and slow, but occasionally I would like to upgrade a package from homebrew.

Unfortunately if a binary download fails, it will attempt to install from source, which will in most cases cause it to download even more dependencies, actually making the situation worse.

**Is there a way to inhibit building from source?** I would prefer to just let it fail and retry later when I have a better connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
brew install --force-bottle myformula
```

According to the [brew man page](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage):

> If --force-bottle is passed, install from a bottle if it exists for the current or newest version of macOS, even if it would not
>                 normally be used for installation.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem.